# Mysql Trigger Prolem

Tags: mysql, mysql-error-1064

I got 2 Table which is Transaction and Product

```
DELIMITER $$

CREATE TRIGGER total_value
  AFTER UPDATE ON product
  FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    UPDATE transaction
       SET transaction.TotalPrice = product.ProductPrice * Transaction.OrderedQty   
END;

DELIMITER ;
```

But it Shows Unexpection Error

Im Sorry Actually My Problem is I want to insert a Total Value in my Transaction to calculate the qty and product price where product price is from another table which is product table and My Problem is I Don't know a Right Syntax for that :(

[Here is my Transaction](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NfvK7.png)

[Here is My Product](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9rL4Q.png)

Comment: It just says _"Unexpection Error"_?

Comment: How do you execute this? What are your exact reproduction steps? `DELIMITER` is for the command processor in the command-line client.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you want to do this and upodate with the new Productprice.

```
DELIMITER $$

CREATE TRIGGER total_value
  AFTER UPDATE ON product
  FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    UPDATE transaction tr
       SET tr.TotalPrice = NEW.ProductPrice * tr.OrderedQty
          Where tr.ProductID = NEW.PRoduktID;  
END;

DELIMITER ;
```

So it only Updates the column and totalprice when the productID si equal

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you're executing this in the command-line client (so the `DELIMITER` command is valid), you simply forgot to terminate your `UPDATE` statement:

```
UPDATE transaction
   SET transaction.TotalPrice = product.ProductPrice * Transaction.OrderedQty;
```

Notice the `;` at the end.

Also you wrote `;` instead of `$$` at the end of the trigger text, despite having just changed the delimiter to `$$`.